# Does IE not support the base tag?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, meta-tags

I am unclear on IE's support for the `<base>` tag. Some articles suggest that it only works with an absolute href path. But it won't work for me.

```
<base href="http://domain.net/qu/en/" />

<a href="sample">Sample Link</a>
```

On chrome and FF, clicking on the link will take me to `http://domain.net/qu/en/sample` but in IE9, it's taking me to `http://domain.net/qu/sample`

I tried this with a relative `<base>` as well, and it doesn't appear to work.

I have only tested this in IE9.08

Comment: Is the `<base>` tag the first thing in your `<head>`? It should probably be :)

Comment: @Daan: It is (At first, I thought you were mocking me)

Comment: Well, you didn't say, and it was the first thing that I thought of as a possible reason for this problem. So I figured I'd ask. Didn't mean to come across as if I was taking the mickey, sorry! Glad you've solved the problem now :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IE has always supported `<base href>`. By the specifications, it has always been defined only when the `href` value is an absolute URL, though some browsers have had interpreted it even in the case of a relative URL. It must be placed in the `<head>` part of the document; otherwise browsers may ignore it. The base address can only be set once in a document. (If this is violated, browsers tend to ignore all but the first of them.)

In this case, my guess is that there is some character, outside any tags, before the `<base>` tag. Consider this:

```
 <base href="http://domain.net/qu/en/" />
<a href="sample">Sample Link</a>
```

This is invalid because of the no-break space character before the `<base>` tag. In HTML parsing, the no-break space, which is not a whitespace character, implicitly closes the `<head>` element and opens the `<body>` element. This means that the `<base>` tag would now be in the `<body>`. Some browsers may still accept it, but as the document cited in Tieson T’s answer says: “Internet Explorer 7 [and newer] strictly enforces the use of the **base** tag within the **head** of the document, and will ignore misplaced tags.”

To check things out, use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org)—it will among other things report problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, IE 7 and newer do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx